# name error in python involving multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, class, for-loop

it gives a name error saying i didnt define a,b,c,d
i have tried to add the a,b,c,d to the empty list in the self.passengers but it comes up with another error
here is the code below

```
 class Flight():
        def __init__(self, capacity):
            self.capacity = capacity
            self.passengers = []
    
        def add_passenger(self, name):
            if not self.open_seats():
                return False
            self.passengers.append(name)
            return True
    
        def open_seats(self):
            return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)
    
    flight = Flight(3)
    
    people = (a , b,c,d)
    a = input("!st passenger: ")
    b = input("2nd passenger: ")
    c = input("3rd passenger: ")
    d = input("4th passenger: ")
    for person in people:
        success = flight.add_passenger(person)
        if success:
            print(f"Added {person} to flight successfully")
        else:
            print(f"No available seats for {person}")
```

Comment: declare people after a/b/c/d

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's a typo/not reproductible.

Answer (score 2):

You define a,b,c,d after you call them in "people=". Move the definition up before setting the people tuple and it works

```
class Flight():
        def __init__(self, capacity):
            self.capacity = capacity
            self.passengers = []
    
        def add_passenger(self, name):
            if not self.open_seats():
                return False
            self.passengers.append(name)
            return True
    
        def open_seats(self):
            return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)
    
flight = Flight(3)
a = input("!st passenger: ")
b = input("2nd passenger: ")
c = input("3rd passenger: ")
d = input("4th passenger: ")
people = (a , b,c,d)

for person in people:
    success = flight.add_passenger(person)
    if success:
        print(f"Added {person} to flight successfully")
    else:
        print(f"No available seats for {person}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unindent everything from flight = Flight(3) and put the inputs before the people tuple.